# Unique URL routing through KONG

Tags: api, curl, restful-architecture, api-design, kong

Right now I have the following implementation working with kong. 
What I have working now :

[image: What I have working now]

I'm able to curl through the host where kong resides and have it forward the api request to the appropriate api host depending on what the host header contains. The results are correctly returned to me as well.

What I want to be able to do instead is curl using the api host address and have it go through kong. How would I approach this? I'm not very familiar with api frameworks or patterns and would appreciate some direction.

What I would like to happen:
[image: What I would like to happen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But by doing that you are going to loose the benefit of kong. According to me we are adding kong to have a controlled access to the APIs. If you call apis directly, where they are hosted, then kong will not be able to provide the benefits.

For your problem, where you don't want to pass the host in the header you can add host to the kong when you are adding the API to kong. With that whenever request lands for api_x_command it will go to the defined host in the kong environment.

So your URLs will be like this

`https://kongurl/api_1_command - will go to https://api_1_host/api_1_command
and
https://kongurl/api_2_command - will go to https://api_2_host/api_2_command`

Check the url, it will always point to Kong and command will be deciding factor, with host setting done in Kong.

Comment: how do you achieve this ? could you read this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61687855/801448

Answer (score 0):

To your question. It's good to go via kong(not directly to your service IP). So that you can expose only kong's ipAddress to the outside world and also get al benefits that kong is providing. If you are so worried about security, add proxy behind kong such that even kong won't be exposed.

Client <--> Proxy <--> Kong <--> Service1..N

I am new to kong. So guys please let me know if I answered wrongly. Please correct me.

BTW, one more point: For every request, if you don't want to set "Host" header then the best way to achieve this is not setting "hosts" while configuring a route. Such that for every request client no need to set "Host" header. This will be useful in some cases.

https://discuss.konghq.com/t/setup-for-one-service-without-host-header/805